# How to get ENI attached to lambda using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I understand that lambda attaches itself to an ENI when it is woken up from it's cold state. How do I get a handle on the ENI ( or all the ENIs) attached to the lambda using boto3?

Comment: There appears to be more to this question that you haven't mentioned.  Why do you need the ENIs?

Comment: Just to experiment and see if I can explicitly attach an EIP to the lambda ENI during runtime. Wanted to verify how would lambda behave if I set the reserved concurrency to 1. Would it always default to a particular ENI or not. I there a  preference wrt to subnets / AZ. How would it handle simultaneous requests. too many things which can't be mentioned in a single question.

Answer (score 4):

The ENI created by lambda when you put it in a VPC is an **AWS lambda-managed ENI**.

There is no a single API call to get the ENI associated with a particular lambda function (to my knowledge at least).

Thus you would have to do it yourself. For example using [describe_network_interfaces](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_network_interfaces) call to get the list of all ENI in a given vpc, and then filter out non-lambda ones.

For the filtering, a description of ENI could be useful. I checked now and the ENI which lambda service creates has the description in the form of:

`AWS Lambda VPC <function name>`

and the owner is `amazon-aws`.

I'm not certain if the ENI description is absolutely fixed and unique, but this seems as a good start.

Answer (score 1):

To have Lambda delete the network interface, do the following:

1. For each unpublished Lambda function (the $LATEST version) that Lambda ENI Finder listed, change the Amazon VPC configuration to use a different subnet and security group. Or, you can disconnect the function from the Amazon VPC entirely.
2. For each published Lambda function version listed, delete the function version. Published versions can't be edited, so the VPC configuration can't be changed.
3. Run Lambda ENI Finder again to verify that the network interface is no longer in use. If no other functions or function versions are listed in the output, Lambda deletes the network interface for you within 24 hours.

For more information, you can check the below AWS Link

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-eni-find-delete/

I hope this helps you.